# How can I specify optional dependencies using setup.py and extra_requires?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, openwisp

Is there a way to specify optional dependencies when using `python setup.py develop`?

For example, say I have this package:

```
pip install openwisp-utils[users]
```

How can I install [openwisp-utils](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-utils) for development by telling setuptools to install the optional dependencies listed in `extra_requires['users']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an alternative to `python setup.py develop` (which unfortunately doesn't seem to support `extra_requires`):

```
pip install -e .[users]
```